# How to launch a Machine Learning model?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, predictive-modeling, prediction, machine-learning-model

First of all thank you for taking your time to read my question. I have done a Machine Learning model with a dataset (The famous one about Cancer) and I want to know how can I do to predict the results for new variables. I think that I have to keep training the data (often) to have more accured data to use in my prediction but for predicting new data, ¿Is as simple as changing the test data (y variable) to the new data? Thank you so much for taking your time and any help would be appreciate it.

Comment: Can you give some more details on what software tools you used to train your model and what specific model you used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally , at the first time, I used this link to do predictions in deep learning:

https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-make-classification-and-regression-predictions-for-deep-learning-models-in-keras/

if you're using another algorithm (not neural networks), which one?

Comment: See this link (RF and DT are used) :    https://medium.freecodecamp.org/using-machine-learning-to-predict-the-quality-of-wines-9e2e13d7480d

Comment: Thank you so much. The last part was what I was looking for.